# Rails ActiveRecord relations - avoiding writing .blank? checks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

This is more a style question than anything.

When writing queries, I always find myself checking if the result of the query is blank, and it seems - I dunno, overly verbose or wrong in some way.

EX.

```
def some_action
  @product = Product.where(:name => params[:name]).first
end
```

if there is no product with the name = params[:name], I get a nil value that breaks things.

I've taken to then writing something like this

```
def some_action
  product = Product.where(:name -> params[:name])
  @product = product if !product.blank?
end
```

Is there a more succinct way of handling nil and blank values? This becomes more of a headache when things rely on other relationships

EX.

```
def some_action
  @order = Order.where(:id => params[:id]).first
  # if order doesn't exist, I get a nil value, and I'll get an error in my app
  if !@order.nil?
    @products_on_sale = @order.products.where(:on_sale => true).all
  end
end
```

Basically, is there something I haven;t yet learned that makes dealing with nil, blank and potentially view breaking instance variables more efficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If its just style related, I'd look at Rails' Object#[try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method or perhaps consider something like [andand](https://github.com/raganwald/andand).

Using your example, try:

```
def some_action
  @order = Order.where(:id => params[:id]).first
  @products_on_sale = @order.try(:where, {:onsale => true}).try(:all)
end
```

or using andand:

```
def some_action
  @order = Order.where(:id => params[:id]).first
  @products_on_sale = @order.andand.where(:onsale => true).andand.all
end
```

Comment: Very interesting, two methods I had not seen before. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well even if you go around "nil breaking things" in your controller, you'll still have that issue in your views. It is much easier to have one `if` statement in your controller and redirect view to "not found" page rather than having several `if`s in your views.

Alternatively you could add this

```
protected
  def rescue_not_found
  render :template => 'application/not_found', :status => :not_found
end
```

to your `application_controller`. See more here: https://ariejan.net/2011/10/14/rails-3-customized-exception-handling

Comment: Cool, this is just the sort of information I was looking for. Thanks!